# How to get maximum height of piled boxes?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There are set of **20** boxes with parameters `{height, length, width}`.
One box can be piled on another if its `{length_of_first, width_of_first}` is less or equal than `{length_of_second, width_of_second}`, i.e.

`length_of_first <= length_of_second && width_of_first <= width_of_second`.
The boxes can be rotated on any side

```
BoxSizes rotateRight(const BoxSizes& box) {
    BoxSizes box_sizes(box);

    int height = box_sizes.height;
    int width = box_sizes.width;
    int length = box_sizes.length;

    box_sizes.length = width;
    box_sizes.height = length;
    box_sizes.width = height;

    return box_sizes;
}

BoxSizes rotateOnward(const BoxSizes& box) {
    BoxSizes box_sizes(box);

    int height = box_sizes.height;
    int width = box_sizes.width;
    int length = box_sizes.length;

    box_sizes.length = height;
    box_sizes.height = length;
    box_sizes.width = width;

    return box_sizes;
}
```

The main is goal is to get the highest pile of boxes.
It's not mandatory to use all boxes, but one box must be used only once!
Example. Given two boxes:

```
{27, 24, 35},
{76, 36, 3}
```

I can pile two boxes but it is better to not pile them and just take second one and rotate it and get `76`.

**What a method should I use to solve this problem** because I cannot use bruteforce because I need to consider `3` rotations for each box and so I need to run `(3 + 1) ^ 20` cases (`+1` because a box may be not used)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong here, but I think you can pile those two boxes in the example. First put {76, 36} on the ground (height 3), and put on top {27, 24} (height 35). Total height is then 38. Which is smaller than 76, so your solution is actually correct. But the boxes ARE "pilable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is going to be a hybrid approach that uses dynamic programming to generate upper bounds on pile heights, and then an A* search to find the solution.

First, let's construct a graph with 60 nodes representing having just put one of the 20 boxes in each of 3 orientations.  Add to it one more for the empty pile.

Your arrows are A -> B if B can be piled on A.  The "can be piled" means that it fits your piling rule with the following extra rules.  If length and width match, you can only pile the shorter on the longer.  If box dimensions are identical, enforce an arbitrary order.

The reason for these restrictions is that if there is a valid answer that doesn't follow those additional rules, you can rearrange boxes to find one of the same height that does.  So we only need to look for arrangements that follow those rules.  And with those loops there will be no loops in our graph.

Next, from a simple recursive graph search, for each box with orientation we can find the highest pile that could be made on it, ignoring the duplication rule.  Record those 61 heights.

Those heights are an overestimate of how tall a pile you can construct.  But we have not tried to enforce the rule about never reusing a box.  Let's fix that with an A* search.

We need a [Priority Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) that returns the largest priority first.  (A max-heap will do nicely.)  With that, our search goes as the following pseudo-code.

```
queue.add((max height on empty ground, 0, empty path))
while True: # loop condition terminates at end.
    (priority, height, path) = queue.pop()
    if priority = height:
        EXIT HERE, HEIGHT IS ANSWER AND PATH IS OPTIMAL PILING
    else:
        queue.add((height, height, path))
        for oriented box that can pile on last in path: # in graph above
            if box not in path:
                new_height = height + height of box
                queue.add((
                    new_height + max_height on orientation,
                    new_height,
                    path with orientation added))
```

What this will do is start with an empty path, put every orientation into the queue, and then will greedily explore trying the tallest piling you found the first time, backtracking whenever it runs into the duplicated box criterion.  The priority we get will always be an upper limit on how tall the tallest pile can be.  The height is the height of this pile so far.  Which is why when we find a pile whose actual height matches the priority, that is the best possible answer.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked out for me! Later I'll attach working code

Answer (score 0):

As Mr."btilly" said, we should create a graph from all possible rotations of the boxes.

*Each node represent a rotated (or original shape) box.*

An edge between nodes can exist only if second box can be piled on first box.

So, let's introduce a structure that describes box's shape:

```
struct BoxSizes {
    int length{};
    int width{};
    int height{};
    int type{-1};
    int num_of_box{};

    BoxSizes(const BoxSizes&) = default;
    BoxSizes(const std::vector<int>& box, int type, int num_of_box) : length(box[0]), width(box[1]), height(box[2]), type(type), num_of_box(num_of_box) {}
    /*Some helpful methods*/
```

We give box shapes like that:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> box_sizes = {
            {269, 152, 375},
            {45, 8, 259},
            {37, 113, 98},
            {685, 40, 35}
};
```

Let's create all rotations of boxes:

```
std::vector<BoxSizes> all_rotated_box;

for (const auto& box_as_vector : box_sizes) {
     /*Don't pay attention on type and count*/
     const auto& box = BoxSizes(box_as_vector, type++, count);
     count += 3;
     all_rotated_box.emplace_back(box);
     all_rotated_box.emplace_back(rotateRight(box));
     all_rotated_box.emplace_back(rotateOnward(box));
}

/*Let's sort them!*/
std::sort(all_rotated_box.begin(), all_rotated_box.end());
```

So, let's introduce a structure `Node`

```
struct Node {
        int x, y, z;
        int type;
        Node() = default;
        Node(int _x, int _y, int _z, int type) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z), type(type) {}
        bool operator==(Node a) {
            return (x == a.x) && (y == a.y);
        }
};

std::vector<Node> nodes;

/*From vector of boxes to vector of nodes*/
std::transform(all_rotated_box.begin(), all_rotated_box.end(), std::back_inserter(nodes),
                   [](const auto& box) { return  Node(box.length, box.width, box.height, box.type); });
```

Let's create a graph:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Graph(nodes.size(), std::vector<int>(nodes.size(), 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        auto x = nodes[i].x;
        auto y = nodes[i].y;
        auto type = nodes[i].type;

        for (int j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            auto x_ = nodes[j].x;
            auto y_ = nodes[j].y;
            auto type_ = nodes[j].type;

            if(i == j) {
                Graph[i][j] = nodes[i].z;
            }

            if(type == type_ || (x == x_ && y == y_))
                continue;

            if((x < x_ || x <= x_) && (y < y_ || y <= y_) ||
               (x < y_ || x <= y_) && (y < x_ || y <= x_)) {
                Graph[i][j] = std::abs( nodes[j].z);
            }

        }
    }
```

So, the main loop is:

```
for(auto j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
        std::deque<int> q;

        q.push_back(j);

        std::vector<int> heighest(nodes.size(), 0);
        heighest[j] = Graph[j][j];

        while (!q.empty()) {
            std::vector<int> adjacent_nodes;

            auto curr{q.front()};
            q.pop_front();

            for (int i = 0; i < Graph[0].size(); i++) {
                if (Graph[curr][i] > 0 && i != curr) {
                    adjacent_nodes.push_back(i);
                }
            }

            for (auto node : adjacent_nodes) {
                heighest[node] = std::max(heighest[node], heighest[curr] + Graph[curr][node]);
                q.push_back(node);
            }
        }

        the_heighest = std::max(the_heighest, *std::max_element(heighest.begin(), heighest.end()));
    }
```

You can check here https://github.com/Ayrtat/codeforces/blob/master/BoxRight.cpp